# Have either of these sequences been cataloged?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

Let $x(n)$ be the remainder when $p(n + 2)$ is divided by 3, where $p(n)$ is the $n$-th prime.

Let $y(n)$ = $x(n)$ - 1.

Then $\{y(n)\}$ is a binary sequence, that is, is a sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s.

Let $a(n)$ be the number specified by the concatenation of the binary digits $y(1)...y(n)$, and let $b(n)$ be the number specified by the concatenation of the binary digits $y(n)...y(1)$.

Have either of the sequences $\{a(n)\}$ and $\{b(n)\}$ been cataloged?

Comment: You need to start with primes larger than 3.

Comment: You could try computing the first terms of it and looking at the OEIS, but I doubt it. Usually, people don't spend much time studying sequences obtained by doing seemingly random things.

Comment: @Maesumi: Thanks. I have made the edit.

Answer (score 1):

> $\{p(n + 2)\} = 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, \dots$
>
> $\{x_n\} = 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, \dots$
>
> $\{y_n\} = 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, \dots$
>
> $\{a(n)\} = 1, 2, 5, 10, 21, 42, 85, 171, 342, 684, \dots$
>
> $\{b(n)\} = 1, 1, 5, 5, 21, 21, 85, 213, 213, 213, \dots$

Neither of these last two sequences is in [OEIS](http://oeis.org), although [one sequence](http://oeis.org/A215410) somewhat coincidentally comes pretty close to $a(n)$.  This is a pretty good indication that the sequences haven't been studied so far.

Comment: It sounds like you swallowed some fast acting yeast.

Comment: @EsperantoSpeaker1 what do you mean ?

Comment: Judging by your bloated reply.

Comment: @EsperantoSpeaker1 I assume you are referring to my last paragraph. I apologize for that paragraph, it was written obnoxiously. Now what are you accomplishing by insulting me on the internet?

Comment: I accomplished getting an apology out of you.

Comment: @EsperantoSpeaker1 I think that paragraph was out of line. The tone was belittling, suggesting I knew more about research math than I had any right to. I am also sorry for reacting defensively. Out of curiosity: was that paragraph so demoralizing or insulting that it stuck in your mind all these years? It is something I would like to know if my offhand comments have the potential for such great effects.

Comment: I suppose that it was a little annoying when it first occurred, but I don’t really remember. This question came to the top of my queue when someone upvoted it a few days ago. When I came back to it, I was reacting again as if the question and responses were all new. Again, I found the paragraph annoying, but this time, while out shopping and wondering if I could come up with a nifty put-down to an under-the-radar jibe, it occurred to me in a flash as I was reaching for the fast-acting yeast that was on my list. The rest is history.